# Content type which contains a content creation as a slip form

Tags: entities, nodes, users

I'm quite new to Drupal and I've encountered a quite complicated problem.

I've created a role called "**Event coordinator**" authorized to create a content type entitle "**Events**" that has a title and and a description, and for which comments are disabled. Here is a sample of it:

- Title: "Join Our Club".
- Description: "It will be fun".

I've also created another role called "**Audience**" which will be used by the user who will attempt to join the event detailed in the content created by the "Event coordinator".

The "Audience" should create a "**Slip**" content which will have a request message. And it should be sent to the targetted "Events".

A "Slip" that gets created will be put (somehow) in another content which is the "Events". The "Event coordinator" then will choose whom will join an event based on the "Slips" that were created.

Only the "Event coordinator" and the owner of a slip (created by "audience") will be able to see a "Slip".

I've tried to use the "entity-registration" but it's not that flexible. I mean as an "Event coordinator" I'm not able to see all the "Slips" from all "Events" I created. It will just show the "Slips" when you view the content of a single "Event".

Any suggestions about which module(s) I could use to implement this?

Comment: What is a "slip" (in this context)? And is that another content type? If not how is it implemented?

Comment: the "slip" I'm talking about is a created content by an audience that will be put (somehow) in a another content which is the "events". the event-coordinator then will choose whom will join the event base on the audience's "slips" content send.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using a combination of the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) and [Flag](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag) modules. Some more details about how to use these modules in this case:

- To create a "slip", just implement that using a "flag" (used for content type = "Event"), via which "Audience" can indicated something like "I would like to attend".
- Whenever an Event gets flagged by a user, use the Rules module to notify the Event coordinator, by sending an appropriate eMail. As an alterative, create a view (using the Views module), that lists all "flagged events".
- "Event Coordinators" should be authorized to see all "flagged" Events, while a user who flagged an event can only see which events that user flagged (not which events were flagged by some other user).
- After the "Event Coordinator" reviews a flagged event (= Request to attend) and decides to approve it, create a "relationship" between that user and the event, via a field like "Attendees" added to the "Event" (of type "user reference", with multiple (unlimited or not?) possible values).

Voilà, just some basic Rules/Flag stuff, right?

Answer (score 0):

You may use [Organic groups](https://www.drupal.org/project/og) module

> Enable users to create and manage their own 'groups'. Each group can have subscribers, and maintains a group home page where subscribers communicate amongst themselves.

"event-coordinator" will be group administrator and he will create and edit any content in the group. "audience" will be usual group member and he will edit only own content in the group

Comment: can it create multiple groups? I mean, if I'm an "event coordinator", I will create three groups: "golf Club", "tennis club", "volley club". then the event coordinator will be the head for each of those groups.

Comment: Yes, one user can create multiple groups

Comment: last questions, can it give me a view or reports. I mean, number of audiences a month.

Comment: You can create your own view to do it. Organic groups module has integration with Views module